# Difference between list added to list and list multiplied by scalar

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I wanted to duplicate the list by itself , so found these two approaches for doing this. This below code is running faster than the other statement.  can you explain why first one executing so much faster than the second one.

First Approach :

```
   l = [1,2,3,...1000000]
    
    return l * 2
```

Second Approach :

```
   l = [1,2,3,...1000000]
    
    return l + l
```

edit : even this below code running slow as well

```
   l = [1,2,3,...1000000]
    
   l.extend(l) 

   return l
```

[image: first code]

[image: second code]

[image: thrid code]

Comment: a naive argumentation: `l*2` needs to process `l` only and perform an operation, `l+l` needs to apply an operation between two objects, `extend` update the same memory location

Comment: may be, but underhood should be same right when they do the same work.

Comment: Ideally they should be equivalent, but `l * 2` allows for easier optimizations.

Comment: You can compare implementations of list multiplication ([`list_repeat()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/138db8e48b0bb006b1561f8ec76ade97afc6cbd7/Objects/listobject.c#L552), [`list_inplace_repeat()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/138db8e48b0bb006b1561f8ec76ade97afc6cbd7/Objects/listobject.c#L744) ) and concatenation ([`list_concat()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/138db8e48b0bb006b1561f8ec76ade97afc6cbd7/Objects/listobject.c#L510), [`list_inplace_concat()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/138db8e48b0bb006b1561f8ec76ade97afc6cbd7/Objects/listobject.c#L1002)).

Comment: Basically, the main difference between implementations is reference management. `list_repeat()` set reference count using [`Py_SET_REFCNT()`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/structures.html#c.Py_SET_REFCNT) and `list_concat()` uses [`Py_INCREF()`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/refcounting.html#c.Py_INCREF). Implementations of both functions are quite similar, I doubt that there's serious difference in performance.

Comment: @OlvinRoght added screenshot for time it took

Comment: The difference with `extend()` is because it can be given an arbitrary iterable. So it can't use list-specific optimizations.

Comment: @Barmar to elaborate, `.extend` will essentially be `.append` in a loop, and while that is going to be linear time complexity, the re-sizing required will add to the overall runtime... but actually, [it does special case `list` and `tuple` objects](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4f85cec9e2077681b3dacc3108e646d509b720bf/Objects/listobject.c#L872)

Comment: @Ravi, I briefly sniffed through both functions and found no bottleneck which could cause such a difference. As I told before, the only significant difference is that `list_repeat()` calls `Py_SET_REFCNT()` once while `list_concat()` calls `Py_INCREF()` two times, but I can't say whether it makes any difference or not. I've attached links to CPython sources in comment above, so you can dig into sources by yourself.

Comment: Note, when you extend a list with itself, it has to make a copy, so that might explain the slowdown... see the above link.

Comment: @OlvinRoght ah, just glancing at the code, I think with `Py_INCREF`, it has to call that for each individual addition (so twice overall in this case), for `Py_SET_REFCNT`, it only calls it once per item.

Comment: The difference would be even more significant for `l * 5` versus `l + l + l + l + l`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, that's exactly what I've meant in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72651109/10824407#comment128332446_72651109) comment. The way to confirm this assumption is to compare performance of `l * 3` with `l + l + l`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Actually, the special-case code for `list.extend(list)` also has a special case for `self.extend(self)` that doesn't require making a copy. It grows itself first, then copies the first half to the second half.

Comment: @Barmar well, I'm just going by the comment that says `extending self to self requires making a copy first`, I'm pretty sure it does when it does `iterable = PySequence_Fast(iterable, "argument must be iterable");`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I wonder if that comment is obsolete, bcause I don't see where it's making a copy. There's a later comment that says **note that we may still have self == iterable here for the situation
a.extend(a), but the following code works in that case too.  Just make
sure to resize self before calling PySequence_Fast_ITEMS.**

Comment: @Barmar maybe, but I'm pretty sure `iterable = PySequence_Fast(iterable, "argument must be iterable")` creates a copy, but I'm not sure, see: https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/sequence.html#c.PySequence_Fast

Comment: What Python version are you using?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga From https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/897bc6f9282238d5fb32d232ab62d30675244736/Doc/c-api/sequence.rst: ```As a CPython implementation detail, if *o* is already a sequence or list, it will be returned.``` So no copy is made.

Comment: Rather surprising speed differences. I would've guessed that the creation of the original list and its billion int objects, which you included in the timing, takes the majority of the time. I'd do some testing myself, but I can't execute images...

Comment: Btw you messed up the function using extend.

Comment: Did you run the three versions completely independently? Or did the later ones have to pay for the deletion of the `asdd` from the previous one?

Comment: @KellyBundy, there's tiny difference in [my benchmark](https://tio.run/##lY/BCsIwDIbvfYqwyzoVcfUiQp8lVG210Hal6w4@fe1Wx0RRMJdA/v/Pl/h7vHVuf/AhpV5YbyQa3UfgMDYahLtK2u6mahpCLlKBGty5paY5EsgVZByCAwNrMIvOPvUVMEK0AkQnrEQEzqFGtEI7xLqYtfVdiBC1lTpOEx@0i7QqzKbaPLVtabPwcvro6TPT80qFzsJMmHdPgWxZEjngBnuSgbflyzcu@8Zl/3LZT25KDw), but definitely not same as author show.

Comment: @OlvinRoght I suspect most of their speed differences are due to mistakes on their side. The  optimization you talked about earlier is new, btw, I think in 3.11.

Comment: @OlvinRoght While you excluded the *creation* of the data, you included the *deletion* of the doubled data. That also takes significant time. See the results in my answer.

Comment: @KellyBundy, actually I've executed benchmark code on my local machine with 3.11.0b2 interpreter and difference in performance was just few percents. And I haven't go too far with optimizations of benchmark because my main task was to check are there 100% performance difference as author mentioned. Great answer though!

Comment: @OlvinRoght What speed difference do you get on 3.11 if you shuffle the list (`random.shuffle(sample_list)` right after creating it)?

Comment: @KellyBundy All three tests run independently.

Comment: And the Python version? Also, in what software are you running it?

Answer (score 2):

I believe most of the timing differences are due to improper timing. In particular, your last version using `extend` returns not the extended list but the result of the `extend` call, which is `None`. That means the list loses all references and gets deleted. And all its elements as well. And you include that deletion time. You also include the creation time. That's the same for all three, but it's an overhead that dilutes actual differences. I also suspect that you run your tests sequentially so that later ones suffer from having to delete the result of the previous one (and possibly from having less memory to work with).

I did three cycles where I measured the time components separately (with 10^7 elements and Python 3.10.2, see the full code at the end of this answer):

```
315 ms  create
157 ms  multiply
158 ms  add
 80 ms  extend
156 ms  delete

307 ms  create
157 ms  multiply
157 ms  add
 78 ms  extend
158 ms  delete

316 ms  create
168 ms  multiply
156 ms  add
 92 ms  extend
190 ms  delete
```

Your start list has a billion elements. They take 32 GB of memory. The list and the doubled list add 24 GB. If you indeed run them sequentially, the previous result is still in memory, so you have (32+16)+(32+24) = 104 GB of data in memory. Unless you have that much actual free memory, you likely suffer from page faults. That would reduce the impact of the creation of the `int` objects and explain why that part is so much more significant in my measurements than in yours.

The `*=` has also been [optimized](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/90393) recently, but only in Python 3.11, which hasn't been released yet, so I doubt you're using it. Also, that could only help explain why `*=` is faster for you than `+`. Not why `extend` is so much slower for you than the others, when it should be *faster*. So I believe your time differences are simply mainly due to memory issues and improperly including deletion times (your `+` snippet having to delete the result of your `*=` snippet, and your `extend` snippet having to delete both the result of the `+` snippet and its own result).

Code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZDdTsMwDIXv@xS@mZaUMjF6MYS0Z4kCdUak/FSuJ7Gn75ymFBDCdz7ns3Xs8cYfOfUvI81zgjMcn9r21DQDOngntIxKvzYgdQn5zQYISxOEDH5iRTZdUCWt60i8BvZjuH0NEfKVkuAtPFfCDsMf80G2LiZ@MqbND4e1D/oXX9kBA/6TTqxCOcoR2Ef0DD6OmVgcZyWiKSqBnRZbyExgwCeo5/Tr0iK7ItdPdNt5XTmjW@N2a5Q6U4rlO2Wx0ptEIrkf/TcCj8CbXJLT1o3kE6v9rh8gTrCHHSiWTx6x1x24gzHJRjSmbq2wnuc7)):

```
n = 10**7

def create():
    global l
    l = list(range(n))

def multiply():
    return l * 2

def add():
    return l + l

def extend():
    l.extend(l)
    return l

def delete():
    global l
    del l

from timeit import default_timer as time

for _ in range(3):
    for f in create, multiply, add, extend, delete:
        t = time()
        r = f()
        t = time() - t
        del r
        print('%3d ms ' % (t * 1e3), f.__name__)
    print()
```

Answer (score -1):

To understand the differences between the different possibilities mentioned in the question you could use the [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) to look at the corresponding bytecode operations.

Deduction concerning speed from bytecode is not trivial but could give a *qualitative* idea of what's going on behind the scenes.

```
from dis import dis

def by_scalar_multiplcation(lst, k):
    return lst * k

def by_addition(lst, lst2):
    return lst + lst2

def by_extension(lst, lst2):
    return lst.extend(lst2)

funcs = (by_scalar_multiplcation, by_addition, by_extension)

for f in funcs:
    print(f.__name__)
    print('='*len(f.__name__))
    dis(f)
```

Output

```
by_scalar_multiplcation
=======================
  9           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (lst)
              2 LOAD_FAST                1 (k)
              4 BINARY_MULTIPLY
              6 RETURN_VALUE
by_addition
===========
 12           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (lst)
              2 LOAD_FAST                1 (lst2)
              4 BINARY_ADD
              6 RETURN_VALUE
by_extension
============
 15           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (lst)
              2 LOAD_METHOD              0 (extend)
              4 LOAD_FAST                1 (lst2)
              6 CALL_METHOD              1
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: How does this help? It doesn't show the performance difference between `BINARY_MULTIPLY` and `BINARY_ADD`. For that you should check the source code links in Olvin's comment above.

Comment: This really isn't helpful in this case because the work is all done below the interpreter level in the C layer.

Comment: the purpose was to give a _qualitative_ understanding of each method. Using `dis` together with a time test could be use to exploit (possible) critical operations as those identified by @Barmar . Maybe supposed to be a step towards the "solution"